# Not able to select any weapon

Tags: far-cry-3

I am now in chapter 2 in Far Cry 3 (Harvest the Jungle). Here I need a gun or weapon to kill Boar but I am not able to select any weapon except grenades. Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

With the default controls, the mouse wheel only allows you to switch between grenades and molotovs.
In order to select the weapons from your weapons slots, you can either:

- press "1", "2", "3" or "4"
- hold "1" to show the weapon wheel
- press "x" to switch to the previous weapon